# Tablas de Dispersión

Tags: java, estructuras-de-datos

Que es una función Hash?
Como funcionan las tablas de Dispersión?
Me explicaron esto en una clase y no lo asimile mucho, podría alguien ayudarme por favor

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Que parte no entendiste? que entendiste? si no, es como que hay que darte la clase de vuelta... buscate algo por internet?